# Changing variables in a script to execute on pageinit

Tags: javascript, ajax, soundmanager2

I have some JavaScript that I would like to execute during the pageinit event however I would be getting the variables/values for this script from an ajax call that happens before. How can I execute this script? For a good example lets say am using soundmanger2.js to autpplay a track using JavaScript however the url for the track will only be gotten after the results are returned from an ajax call. How then can the track actually be played when the page has loaded?

Comment: You call the api when the call is done? Add logic to see if it is loaded yet?

Comment: You can't run soundmanager2 on page init then. Disable it running automatically, and run it manually from your AJAX callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function() {
    /* things to do outside ajax */
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        /* things to do after ajax load */
    });
});
```